# Complex If conditions. Bad practice?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, readability, code-readability

**Context:** I am trying to make sure my player can only sprint if:

1. They are **moving forwards**,
2. The **"Sprint" key is pressed**,
3. They are **grounded.**

```
if ((Input.GetAxis("Vertical") == 1) && Input.GetButton("Sprint") && isGrounded)
        {
            isRunning = true;
            relativeMovementSpeed = playerSprintSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
        }
```

Is this considered **bad practice or poor readability**?

If so, what would be a better(either a standardized or easier to read) way of doing this?

Comment: I don't think it's all that bad, but if anything, I think the `(Input.GetAxis("Vertical") == 1)` hurts readability most. You could pull those out into a separate variable like `bool movingForward = Input.GetAxis("Vertical") == 1;` or something. I've also seen like breaks between the conditions used in this sort of situation as well.

Comment: complex if conditions aren't bad; the entire field of AI and Machine Learning is just a bunch of nested `if`s after all :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with evaluating multiple things in a single `if`. If anything, it's better than than alternative, which would be nesting them.

However, it can become unreadable when this evaluation grows to a larger size. Your current example is (IMHO) still okay, but different people will draw the line at different places.

When it gets to be too complex to easily read, you can abstract the evaluations into small methods, for example:

```
private bool IsMovingForwards()
{
    return Input.GetAxis("Vertical") == 1;
}

private bool IsSprintKeyPressed()
{
    return Input.GetButton("Sprint");
}
```

Which enhances the readability of your `if` block:

```
if (IsMovingForwards() && IsSprintKeyPressed() && isGrounded)
{
    // ...
}
```

This almost exactly repeats your description of the required evaluation logic.

*Edit: just to point out, you are free to choose whether you use a local variable, class property, helper class or method to abstract these individual evaluations. I used methods here but you can approach this in multiple ways depending on your current context. The main goal here is to label the logic in a way that it becomes easy to read.*

Answer (score 1):

I think that @Flater method is nice.
I would change it a bit to use properties :

```
private bool IsMovingForwards
{
    get { return Input.GetAxis("Vertical") == 1; }
}

private bool IsSprintKeyPressed
{
    get { return Input.GetButton("Sprint"); }
}
```

I would create another one for IsRunning :

```
private bool IsRunning
{
    get { return IsMovingForwards && IsSprintKeyPressed && isGrounded; }
}
```

So your code is now like the following :

```
if (IsRunning)
    relativeMovementSpeed = playerSprintSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
```